# Rsync a site directly to Subversion repository

Tags: svn, drupal, cron, rsync, google-code

I have a live drupal website community. I have gone ahead to host the project publicly on Google code. Due to slow internet connectivity, I have not been able to successfully upload my initial copy to the repository (I've also tried svn import).

So I thought, I will write a script that backs up my entire site excluding the database, save it as a tar ball & then rsync it to the repository via cron. How can I go about this?

Comment: You want to use rsync, to commit something to SVN? I re-read your question several times, but cannot see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm not using rsync to commit actually. I want to use rsync to upload (initial upload) to the SVN. By initial upload, I mean before any checkout at all. Just like using svn import.

Answer (score 0):

If you were self hosting, you could probably do this, but google code doesn't give you the kind of access you would need to do this.  If SVN won't work why don't you try one of the other (better) VCS (IE git and mercurial) supported by google code.